# Import Outlook emails into Thunderbird

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, import

I have stored my email from outlook as single messages, i.e., xxx.msg format.

Is there any way to import those emails into Thunderbird?

Do I just need to copy them into a specific folder? A bit clueless right
now.

Comment: What OS?  What version/suite of Office/Outlook?  2007?  2003?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out.
`http://www.processtext.com/abcoutlk.html`

Its costly, so here is a Perl script. Some one will need to help it convert to Thunderbird Plugin or may be create a batch script to run. 
http://www.avtechpulse.com/opensource/email.html

Comment: License for one user $19.95

Answer (score 0):

From [Thunderbird - Importing Outlook Emails and Addressbooks](http://support.real-time.com/tbird/outlook_import.html):

1. From the main Thunderbird window
   click on Tools and then Import...
2. Click on the Mail radio
   button, then click on Next
3. Click on Outlook and then click on
   Next
4. This will show a summary of all the messages that were imported.
   Click on Finish to go back to the main Thunderbird window.
5. If all went well, in the folder list on the left hand side there is now a Outlook Mail folder.
   In this folder you will find your imported messages.

[image]